# Restricting object going out of screen while resizing-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I have an object that I am resizing from bottom to top.

```
private void setStickSize() {
    if (MyInputProcessor.isTap) {
        stickSprite.setSize(stickSprite.getWidth(),stickSprite.getHeight()+500.0f); 
       stickSprite.setY(MathUtils.clamp(stickSprite.getY(),0,700));   
       // MyInputProcessor.isTap = false;
       }
```

Here the sprite is growing out of the screen after calling this in update().I used clamp() to stop this sticksprite within the screen.But no effects on the code.
Why clamp() is not working here?
How can I restrict the sprite resizing effectively within the screen?

I am drawing the sprite like this.

```
    private void drawStick() {   
     stickSprite.setPosition(stick.getX(),stick.getY());

     batch.draw(
            stickSprite.getTexture(),stick.getX(),stick.getY(),
             stickSprite.getWidth()/2 ,stickSprite.getHeight()/2,
             stickSprite.getWidth(),                                                  
             stickSprite.getHeight()*0.01f,                                                  
             stickSprite.getScaleX(),stickSprite.getScaleY(), 0,                  
            stickSprite.getRegionX(),stickSprite.getRegionY(),  
            stickSprite.getRegionWidth(), stickSprite.getRegionHeight(),
             false,false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bound with a condition. Firstly check is your image is out of the screen, if not then increase your image size by a small limit otherwise stop increasing image size.

Like if I have a image(Sprite) and I'm increasing size of that image then we can put a bound before size increment.

```
if(sprite.getY()+sprite.getHeight()<Gdx.graphics.getHeight()){
      float currentHeight=sprite.getHeight();
      currentHeight++;
      sprite.setSize(sprite.getWidth(),currentHeight);
}
```